# Validating an email format in python

Tags: python, email, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program that checks to see if the email is in the valid form. A valid form would be any combination of characters of letters or numbers followed by a `@` sign and then any combination of characters of letters again. I'm not even trying to have a domain such as "gmail.com" it can just be new@gmail for example. I've tried many things and can't seem to figure it out.

```
email = "XXX@XXX"
x = len(email)
    for i in range(x):
        if email[i][0] == "@":
            return False
        elif email[i][-1] == "@":
            return False
        elif not email[i].isalnum():
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Do you allow `.`, `-`, or `+`?

Comment: the only instructions are to have the character "@" between the local part and the domain part. So yes I allows those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com')
```

Comment: thats pretty hard overkill if his validation is just @ in email... +1 all the same

Answer (score 0):

```
return '@' in email[:-1]
```

I think is what you are asking

Comment: looks like he wants to make sure there is at least one character on either side thats not '@'. maybe add a `and email.startswith('@')/endswith('@')` ?

Comment: This validation is too lenient.

Comment: So: `@` is valid ...?

Comment: `return '@' in email[:-1]`

Comment: how do you use return '@' in email[:-1] in context

Answer (score 0):

## This is the code I use in my production system

```
import re

email_format: str = r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9'_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)"
email: str = "test@gmail.com"


if re.match(email_format, email, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("valid email!")
else:
    print("invalid email!")
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a regex.  Something like:

`r.compile('\w*@\w*.com')`

Comment: this will exclude valid emails ... the regex for an email sucks horribly ... http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html  (I definately didnt downvote this though)